# Parse.com TimeZone necessary for pushes?

Tags: parse-platform, timezone

When trying to send a push alert through Parse.com, I came across the following warning:

> Installations without a known timezone will not receive this campaign.

So, how do I make sure Parse knows a user's timezones? Is there any specific code, or does it to that without the need for code/by default, and this is a moot question?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is recorded on a per-Installation basis by the Parse library, and should be automatically updated whenever it is updated by the client.

You can verify that Parse is saving time zones by logging into your account, selecting 'Core' (at top) and 'Installation' (at left). You'll see a list of all current installations - the relevant column is `timeZone`.

The notice that you see when attempting to send a push is just a general reminder, not an indication that there is necessarily anything wrong on your end.

**UPDATE 3/1/2015:**

I found a bug in this, BTW, that some people might run into. So I'm posting it here in case it might help somebody.

In the current version of Parse, there is a bug wherein an iOS device with their Date & Time "Set Automatically" setting disabled will (potentially) return a timeZone that Parse won't understand. In such an event, local-time scheduled push notifications will not be sent to a user with that setting turned off.

I verified this, myself, on two devices. With "Set Automatically" turned on the Parse Installation is set to "America/Los Angeles" (which is accurate for me). With it turned off, it sets it to "US/Pacific". This is still accurate, obviously, but for some reason Parse does not like that value.

I imagine there are a non-trivial number of iOS users with that setting disabled, so I hope Parse fixes this.